# Transfer of music from mobile to ipod

Tags: ipod-touch

I have an iPod. It has a Bluetooth option so I tried to transfer the music from mobile to iPod via Bluetooth. While sending the songs from mobile to iPod it is showing in the mobile that no device is found.

It gets paired but while sending it is showing no device is found. So what should I do?  Is there any different format for iPod?  Will the mp3 format run on iPod?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's iPod doesn't support Bluetooth file transfer profile, [only A2DP, AVRCP, HID & PAN](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647).

MP3s play fine.